# Delete duplicate rows with the same value in all columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with about a half a million rows. As I could see, there are plenty of duplicate rows, so how can I drop duplicate rows that have the same value in all of the columns (about 80 columns), not just one?

df:

```
period_start_time    id    val1    val2    val3
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i53    32      2       10
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i32    32      2       10
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i32    4       2       8
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i32    4       2       8
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i32    4       2       8
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i20    7       7       22
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i20    7       7       22
```

Desired output:

```
period_start_time    id    val1    val2    val3
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i53    32      2       10
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i32    32      2       10
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i32    4       2       8
06.13.2017 22:00:00  i20    7       7       22
```

Comment: did you try calling [`df.drop_duplicates()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print (df)
     period_start_time   id  val1  val2  val3
0  06.13.2017 22:00:00  i53    32     2    10
1  06.13.2017 22:00:00  i32    32     2    10
2  06.13.2017 22:00:00  i32     4     2     8
5  06.13.2017 22:00:00  i20     7     7    22
```