# Delete row if same value in all columns

Tags: awk, duplicates

I have a space-delimited large file with thousands of rows and columns. I would like to remove all lines which have the same value across all columns but the first.

Input:

```
CHROM   108 139 159 265 350 351
SNP1    -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
SNP2    2   2   2   2   2   2
SNP3    0   0   0   -1  -1  -1
SNP4    1   1   1   1   1   1
SNP5    0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Desired

```
CHROM   108 139 159 265 350 351
SNP3    0   0   0   -1  -1  -1
```

There is a similar question asked for the Panda Framework  ([Delete duplicate rows with the same value in all columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759840/delete-duplicate-rows-with-the-same-value-in-all-columns-in-pandas)) and I found a somewhat partial solution that removes lines containing only zero

```
awk 'NR > 1{s=0; for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; if (s!=0)print}' input > outfile
```

but I want to do this for the numbers -1, 0, 1 and 2 in one go with header and 1st column as the identifier.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
awk '{s=$0; gsub(FS $2,FS)} (NF > 1) {print s}' file
```

Which outputs:

```
CHROM   108 139 159 265 350 351
SNP3    0   0   0   -1  -1  -1
```

**How does this work?**

1. **`{s=$0; gsub(FS $2,FS)}`:** This action contains 2 parts:

   - Store the current line in variable `s`
   - Substitute in the current line `$0` all values of the second field including its starting field separator `FS` (`FS $2`) with a field separator `FS`. This has as a side effect the `$0` is redefined and all field variables and the total number of field `NF` are redefined. The field separator `FS` is needed to avoid matching `xx` if `$2=x`
2. **`(NF > 1) {print s}`:** If you have more then 1 field left, print the line, it means you have various numbers.

Comment: this will fail in case we have a line `SNP1    -1  -11  -1  -1  -1  -1` it will print this line too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 as it should. -11 is different from -1

Comment: I meant this will print this line too in output even it shouldn't be printed.

Comment: @kvantour find the number with max length as the pattern. But it will be slower than we compare value in each col.

Comment: I only have single value in each field as I have already removed the duplicates using this command:

awk '!/[0-9]+\|[0-9]+/' input > output

Comment: @WaqasKhokhar, did you try other solutions too once? Always try to check all solutions and give respective posters your response too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes i have checked all the solutions and they all are working perfectly fine. I highly appreciate efforts of all posters :-)

Comment: another variation `awk 'gsub(FS $2,FS $2)<6' file`

Comment: @karakfa this could fail if you have a list with all numbers 1 except one is 11

Comment: @kvantour yes, right.  assumes single digit values otherwise partial matches might occur.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{val=$2;count=1;for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){if(val==$i){count++}};if(count!=(NF-1)){print}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Why not just set `val = $2` and then loop for i starting from 3? There's also no need for a count -- as soon as you find a column not equal to `val`, print the line and break out of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar, sure sir done that now, thank you for making me aware.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
awk 'NR==1;NR>1{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)if($(i+1)!=$i) {print;next}}' file
```

It print the header line.
It loops over the fields until the a difference with the next one is found, then prints it, and go to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Portable Perl solution:

```
$ cat all_row
CHROM   108 139 159 265 350 351
SNP1    -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
SNP2    2   2   2   2   2   2
SNP3    0   0   0   -1  -1  -1
SNP4    1   1   1   1   1   1
SNP5    0   0   0   0   0   0

$ perl -F"\s+" -ane ' { print "$_" if @F[1 .. $#F-1] != $F[1] } ' all_row
CHROM   108 139 159 265 350 351
SNP3    0   0   0   -1  -1  -1

$
```

if the ask is like don't delete if same value in all columns, then

```
$ perl -F"\s+" -ane ' { print "$_" if @F[1 .. $#F-1] == $F[1] } ' all_row
SNP1    -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
SNP2    2   2   2   2   2   2
SNP4    1   1   1   1   1   1
SNP5    0   0   0   0   0   0
```